# When tried to run eclipse,Pypar2 window pops up

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded the adt-bundle for linux and extracted it. Moved the extracted folder in "android" directory in my /home directory. I have also installed openjdk 6. So when i try to run eclipse, Pypar2 window pops up and i just don't understand how do i run eclipse.

If i uninstall PyPar2, it says 'Could not display "`/home/siddhartharao17/Androi...20131030/eclipse/eclipse`".' There is no application installed for executable files. Do you want to search for application to open this file?

Please help me!!

Comment: Could you print the output of `ls -n` of the directory where you have the eclipse executable. You can do the paste on pastebin.com or somewhere and just paste the link here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the executable doesn't have the required permissions.

Simple resolution without using the terminal:

- Right-click the executable -> Properties -> Permissions.
- Check the checkbox that says `Allow executing file as program`.
- Done!

Using the terminal:

- navigate to your dir.
- Execute the following:

  chmod 711 eclipse

Done!

Comment: Get rid of pypar2 if not required - sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove pypar2